# СПП степени или степени с дополнительным следственным оттенком?

Tags: синтаксис

*Ни тоном, ни стилем, ни духом оно даже не напоминало о давних годах любви, а смысл был таким разумным и взвешенным, **что запах гардений на нем показался бы просто бестактным**.*

На что обращать внимание при определении типа таких предложений? Так и не научилась различать их...

Проверьте пожалуйста, правильно ли я рассуждаю: 
(пример оттюда: http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r2_2_2_5)

*Стрелки поймали столько рыбы, что не могли вытащить сеть.*
[сколько они поймали рыбы?] - столько, что потом как следствие не могли вытащить сеть.
Так?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, в обоих примерах СПП степени с дополнительным следственным оттенком. Чтобы правильно уметь распознавать такие предложения, надо учитывать одно важное условие. ССП степени со следственным оттенком, надо учитывать средства связи. ССП (без следственного оттенка) присоединяются к главному союзными словами ***как, сколько, насколько***. ССП со следственным оттенком присоединяются союзами ***что, чтобы*** и относятся к словам так, такой, настолько, столь и оборотам до такой степени, в такой мере и имеют дополнительное значение следствия.

> Ср.: Старушке столько же хотелось повторить свой рассказ, сколько мне его слушать(А. Герцен). ***ССП однозначное.*** 
>   Белые акации пахли так сильно,что их сладкий, приторный, конфетный запах чувствовался на губах и во рту (А. Куприн). ***ССП степени имеет доплнительный оттенок следствия.*** 
>   Руки его дрожали до такой степени, что он был не в состоянии расстегнуть пальто. (А. Чехов)***ССП степени имеет доплнительный оттенок следствия***.