# СПП образа действия с дополнительным значением следствия

Tags: синтаксис

(1) *Она постаралась лечь в постель так, **чтобы он проснулся и ушел.***

Придаточное образа действия с дополнительным значением следствия (в сослагательном наклонении), так?

(2) *Она не пропускала ни одного свидания, которые он устраивал так, **что они выглядели случайными встречами**.*

Придаточное образа действия с дополнительным значением следствия (в изъявительном наклонении), так?

Скажите пожалуйста, можно в (2) заменить *что* на *чтобы* (чисто теоретически)?

Спасибо!

Comment: См.также ваш предыдущий [вопрос](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419308/%d0%a1%d0%9f%d0%9f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы, в обоих примерах СПП степени с дополнительным следственным оттенком. В обоих предложениях изъявительное наклонение, а не сослагательное. В втором примере, конечно, можно употребить союз "чтобы", но тогда поменяется значение: он специально устраивал свиданья так,чтобы они выглядели случайными встречами.

В примере с союзом ***что*** лишь изъясняется, как именно он устраивал свиданья.

Comment: aaahhh ок, súper, поняла! большое спасибо!!! : )